# Get specific key value from array

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to get a specific value using an array key, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

```
$Array = Array(
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2"
);
```

Let's say I want to get the value of "key1" only, and I return the array with the view.

```
return view("myview")->with("arraytoprint", $Array);
```

And I try it with blade but I get `Trying to get property of non-object`...

```
@foreach($arraytoprint as $arr)
{{ $arr->key1 }}
@endforeach
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You access keys in arrays with different notation - `$arr['key1']`

Comment: if you want `key1` value then it would be string, so just print that value its not array. `return view("myview")->with("arraytoprint", $Array['key1']);`

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that you are `trying to get property of non-object` but you are passing in an array. The `->` notation is used for accessing properties in objects, not arrays.

You access keys in PHP arrays using the square bracket notation instead, as below:

```
$arr['key1']
```

In your example you also have no need for the foreach loop if you want to access the keys directly, just simply do:

```
{{ $arraytoprint['key1'] }}
```

If you do want to loop over the values then you can just do the below:

```
@foreach($arraytoprint as $value)
   {{ $value }}
@endforeach
```

And for completeness sake, if you want the keys too you can do:

```
@foreach($arraytoprint as $key => $value)
   {{ $key }} : {{ $value }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: That returns "Illegal string offset"

Comment: BUt you don't need the foreach, just do `$arraytoprint['key1']`

Comment: I can't do ``{{ $arraytoprint['key1'] }}`` it just returns ``Undefined variable``. And the other ways you mentioned doesn't achieve what I'm looking for. I only want to get the value of the key, I don't want anything else than just that 1 value (while still looping). Not the values of all keys...

Comment: If you want just one value, why are you looping? What is the output of `$arraytoprint` then as it sounds like it doesn't even exist in your view from what you just said...

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5, passing data to the view is now done like this :

```
return view("myview", ["arraytopoint"=>$Array]);
```

and access in blade view like this:

```
{{$arraytopoint['key1']}} inside @foreach loop
```

or test value of variable like this :

```
<?php print_r($arraytopoint['key1']); ?>
```